# How to execute a function passed via a prop when a switch/checkbox is checked in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a `customSwitch` which **controls its own state internally**. I need to add a `prop` that accepts a function and, when the switch is "checked" that function should run. Though I don't know how to do that.

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";
import { default as RSwitch } from "react-switch";

export type Props = {
  activeColor?: string,
  checked?: boolean,
  className?: string,
  id?: string | number,
  height?: number,
  label?: string,
  width?: number,
  /**Custom function. */
  onCheck: function,
};

export const CustomSwitch = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    onCheck,
    activeColor,
    checked,
    className,
    id,
    height,
    label,
    width,
  } = props;

  const [check, setCheck] = React.useState(checked);

  const handleChange = () => {
      setCheck(!check);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {label && (
        <label className="switch-label" htmlFor={id}>
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
        <RSwitch
          checked={check}
          checkedIcon={false}
          className={className}
          id={id}
          height={height}
          offColor="#e4e4e4"
          activeBoxShadow="0px 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onColor={activeColor}
          uncheckedIcon={false}
          width={width}
        />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

CustomSwitch.defaultProps = {
  activeColor: "#fd8f67",
  checked: false,
  className: undefined,
  id: undefined,
  height: 20,
  label: undefined,
  width: 38,
  onCheck: () => {}
};

export default CustomSwitch;
```

Comment: `useEffect(()=>yourfunction(), [check])` something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already reacting to the checked state in your `handleChange` function, the easiest way to notify the parent component would be to call `onCheck` alongside `setCheck`.

However, this will only execute whenever the check state is changed to true, and not if the component is mounted with prop `checked === true`:

```
const handleChange = () => {
    const newCheck = !check;
    setCheck(newCheck);
    if (newCheck) onCheck(); // Will only execute if new check value is true.
}
```

Another solution would be to use `useEffect`. This will ensure `onCheck` is executed whenever `check === true`, even on mount:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (check) onCheck(); // Will execute whenever check is true.
}, [check]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleChange = () => {
  if (!check) {
    props.onCheck()
  }

  setCheck(!check);
};
```